# Numeric variable parsed as character when using comma decimals and separator in data.table::fread

Tags: r, fread

The problem occurred when I had a dataset like `quote1`, which lead to var1 being interpreted as character, instead of numeric.

Managed to isolate the issue in the following examples. There seem to be some kind of parsing issue when the first value is missing and it is followed by a date. Can anyone explain if this is a bug or if I need to do something differently?

```
quote1 <- 'var1,var2\n,2014-06-15\n"15,3",2014-06-16'
data.table::fread(quote1, dec = ',', header = TRUE)

# quote 1 output
> data.table::fread(quote1, dec = ',', header = TRUE)
   var1       var2
1:      2014-06-15
2: 15,3 2014-06-16


quote2 <- 'var1,var2\n"15,3",2014-06-15\n"15,3",2014-06-16'
data.table::fread(quote2, dec = ',', header = TRUE)

# quote 2 output
> data.table::fread(quote2, dec = ',', header = TRUE)
   var1       var2
1: 15.3 2014-06-15
2: 15.3 2014-06-16

quote3 <- 'var1,var2\n,"2014-06-15"\n"15,3","2014-06-16"'
data.table::fread(quote3, dec = ',', header = TRUE)

# quote 3 output
> data.table::fread(quote3, dec = ',', header = TRUE)
   var1       var2
1:   NA 2014-06-15
2: 15.3 2014-06-16

quote4 <- 'var1;var2\n;2014-06-15\n"15,3";2014-06-16'
data.table::fread(quote4, dec = ',', header = TRUE, sep = ';')

# quote 4 output
> data.table::fread(quote4, dec = ',', header = TRUE, sep = ';')
   var1       var2
1:   NA 2014-06-15
2: 15.3 2014-06-16
```

Comment: Nice question - so good that I think you've more or less answered it. I can't see how anyone could reasonably expect cases 1 and 4 to be treated differently. So I would lean towards saying it's a bug and would raise it as a github issue. Of course if it is a bug it's a fairly minor one, given that both cases are (in my view) open to interpretation, and you can explicitly set `colClasses`.

Comment: Seems like `colClasses` don't work either:

`data.table::fread(quote2, dec = ',', header = TRUE, colClasses = c("var1" = "numeric"))
# output
   var1       var2
1:      2014-06-15
2: 15,3 2014-06-16`

Comment: That seems more serious then - I would definitely post as a github issue.